# Navigation doesn't work from signUp to Home.[Flutter]

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

When I'm creating a new user after the user is created it doesn't navigate to Home on auth state changes. But if I refresh the app then only it goes to the homepage.

But if I log in the already registered user then it navigates to the homepage as intended.

The problem is after signUP it needs to go to the home page.

Here's what I did:

1. MyApp returns the wrapper where I want to do the logic. It has a stream builder that on auth state changes navigate to respective pages.

```
class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          User user = snapshot.data;
          if (user == null) {
            return Authenticate();
          } else {
            print(user);
            print("going to home page......");
            return HomePage();
          }
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

2. My sign Up logic.

```
 Future registerUser(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _firebaseAuth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User user = userCredential.user;
      return _userFromFirebase(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

I'm just mapping the user according to the user model here.

Comment: instead of using authStateChanges, try using ```currentUser()```

Comment: I tried but still, it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to change the checking status to `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.data != null`? I think `ConnectionState.active` is a different status from `ConnectionState.done`

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConnectionState-class.html